# why use 'NA' = with the possibility of returning a group of values in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have a quick question about the following piece of code. Why can we use `'NA' =`  for the subquery ? I mean, the subquery might return a group of values, not a single one, right? Could anyone tell me the reason? Many thanks for your time and attention.

```
proc sql;
   select lastname, first name
   from sasuser.staffmaster
   where 'NA' = 
      (select jobcategory
       from sasuser.supervisors 
       where staffmaster.empid = supervisors.empid);
quit;
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `EMPID` is a unique ID for an employee (I hope it is?), and each employee has only one supervisor, that query should resolve to a single row every time.  (A single row *for each row returned from the outer query*, of course, which is important.  Think of it like a join - that's basically what that is, a slightly oddly phrased join, which often will be turned into an actual join by the SQL parser.)

In general, however, sure, it could resolve to multiple rows.  SAS will let you do the query, and if it returns just one row it works; if it returns 2+ rows, it fails.  As Quentin pointed out in comments, this is a [correlated subquery](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001361644.htm).

Comment: This is a "correlated subquery", right?  That might be a useful term for OP to read up on. I always find them hard to read.